# Serial-Over-Lan with Dell R410. Invalid data field in request

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool, serial

It's a R410 with the latest BMC firmware.

I can connect it from a MacBook.

```
$ ipmitool -v -I lanplus  -H 192.168.1.23 -U root user list
Password:
ID  Name         Callin  Link Auth  IPMI Msg   Channel Priv Limit
2   root             true    true       true       ADMINISTRATOR
```

But it fails to active SOL.

```
$ ipmitool -I lanplus  -H 192.168.1.23 -U root sol payload enable 1 2
$ ipmitool -I lanplus  -H 192.168.1.23 -U root sol activate

Error activating SOL payload: Invalid data field in request
```

Here is the results from `sol info`.

```
$ ipmitool -I lanplus  -H 192.168.1.23 -U root sol info
Password:
Info: SOL parameter 'Payload Channel (7)' not supported - defaulting to 0x0e
Set in progress                 : set-complete
Enabled                         : true
Force Encryption                : true
Force Authentication            : false
Privilege Level                 : ADMINISTRATOR
Character Accumulate Level (ms) : 50
Character Send Threshold        : 255
Retry Count                     : 7
Retry Interval (ms)             : 480
Volatile Bit Rate (kbps)        : 115.2
Non-Volatile Bit Rate (kbps)    : 115.2
Payload Channel                 : 14 (0x0e)
Payload Port                    : 623
```

How to get the SOL to work in this case?

Comment: Did you fixed this issue ?